# How to check if ALL values of multiple 2d arrays are ALL the same?

Tags: java, arrays

my main problem is the program mustn't allow the user to input only the same digit during all the times the program asks for a value.

for example, the user needs to input values 9 times, and the user only inputs "1" as a value 9 times, the program must take this as an error, meaning there should be variety.

although, the user can still input the same values sometimes, but not ALL THE TIME. The user can enter "1" 2x, 3x, 4x, etc, but not 9x.

for example:

these can be allowed:

enter digit 1: 1

enter digit 2: 2

enter digit 3: 1

enter digit 4: 1

enter digit 5: 3

enter digit 6: 5

enter digit 7: 5

enter digit 8: 5

enter digit 9: 5

however, these can't be allowed:
enter digit 1: 1

enter digit 2: 1

enter digit 3: 1

enter digit 4: 1

enter digit 5: 1

enter digit 6: 1

enter digit 7: 1

enter digit 8: 1

enter digit 9: 1

```
            int [][]array=new int [aa][aa];
```

for the inputting part:

```
        for (row=0;row<aa;row++)
            {
                for (col=0;col<aa;col++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter [" + row + "][" + col + "] = ");
                    array[row][col]=input.nextInt();
                }
            }
```

proceeding after this, the checking if all entered values are all the same should be performed

Comment: consider rephrasing your question as it is very hard to get an overview of your problem. it's often a good idea to provide some code and show some effort you already made so people don't run into the wrong direction

Answer (score 1):

Put the first input into a variable. If one input is not equal to the variable, you have a valid input. Otherwise you can reject it.

Consider the following input, which is invalid

```
11111
```

If one digit is changing at any point you will have a valid input. So checking the first input with all the following ones is enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arr[] = new int[9];
    arr[0] = input.nextInt();
    boolean error = true;
    for (int i=1; i<9 ; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        if (arr[i]!=arr[0])
            error = false;
    }

    if (error)
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    else
        System.out.println("valid");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   int [][] theNumberArray = { {1,4,3},{6,2,3} };//inputs that will not give an error
   //int [][] theNumberArray = { {4,4,4},{6,2,3} };//inputs that will give an error 
   int lastEnteredValue = 0;
   int count = 0;


   for ( int x = 0; x < theNumberArray.length; x++ )
   {
        for ( int k = 0; k < theNumberArray[x].length; k++ )
        {

            if (k > 0 && theNumberArray[x][k] == lastEnteredValue) 
            {
                lastEnteredValue = theNumberArray[x][k];
                count += 1;

                if (count == theNumberArray[x].length - 1)
                {
                    System.out.println(
                    "Error : due to consecutively " + 
                    "inputting the same value!");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            } 
            else {
                lastEnteredValue = theNumberArray[x][k];
            }
        }
   }

   for (int x = 0; x < theNumberArray.length; x++)
   {
        for (int k = 0; k < theNumberArray[x].length; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(theNumberArray[x][k] + " ");
        }
            System.out.println();
   }
```